# How to measure performance of .net desktop application?

Tags: .net, performance

How to measure performance of .net desktop application ?

I have desktop application which is developed using .net

I want to measure request time of each transactions like login and other operations after that

is there any tool by which I can measure accurate time of each request for .net applications?

Comment: You would have to stub that yourself if you want realistic numbers, else use a profiler.

Comment: You could perhaps investigate whether MiniProfiler can help; we only have *examples* of it on ASP.NET, but the core is designed to be framework independent. The only trick is: you'd need to a: decide your own "package of measurement" (with ASP.NET there is an obvious one: the request), and b: write your own UI. I do know that some people are using it in winforms/wpf, so it can be done. It just hasn't been a priority to add more elegant desktop support (because we don't tend to "do" desktop apps so much; just ASP.NET and windows services)

Answer (score 2):

You can use [`dotTrace`](http://www.jetbrains.com/profiler/) from JetBrains for that. Though it's not a free tool (but they provide 10-day free trial version)

Comment: thanks, but is there any free tool which i can use for .net applications performance

Answer (score 1):

I have used both [`ANTS Performance Profiler`](http://www.red-gate.com/products/dotnet-development/ants-performance-profiler/) and [`dotTrace`](http://www.jetbrains.com/profiler/) and I found ANTS to be the more readable and decipherable of the two, both are for money, but both offer trials if you want.